# is, is going to be, or will be

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, aspect

I want to ask you please why the right answer in this sentence

> Easter ____ at the end of April this year

is "is" and not "is going to be"

Comment: as an native English speaker, i would consider all of the answers valid. maybe this is just me being bad at English though.

Comment: No, @flumperious: I concur: they are all good. One more demonstration of the fact that there is no such thing as a future tense in English.

Comment: This looks like it is from materials provided by the Syrian Virtual University. There seems to be a charge to students to participate, 550 euros for each of three levels. If this is a representative sample, the quality is very poor.

Comment: Perhaps this question is focusing on the use of the present tense for future events that are scheduled, timetabled, or detemined by calculation.

Comment: The answers to this question may help: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/153063/9161

Answer (score 2):

If the question is just, which is grammatically correct and logically coherent, they're all valid. I don't know what grounds someone would give for saying that "Easter will be at the end of April this year" or "Easter is going to be ..." is wrong.

Maybe there's some technical grammar rule that these violate, but they all look perfectly good to me. I'm a native English speaker and have been reading and writing the language for close to 60 years. If there's some rule they violate, it's a rule that lots of English speakers routinely ignore.

Several other questions in that screen shot have multiple correct answers.

Comment: Both are fine, I agree. John is coming to dinner. John is going to come for dinner. Same thing.